# Magento admin CMS pages - indivdual edit page gone blank

Tags: php, magento

My magento site admin side has few issues suddenly.

In the admin side, Under CMS -> pages, static blocks, etc are showing the listings like aboutus, home page, etc.

But when I try to edit the individual pages it shows something like blank page with only side tabs that too arranged differently.

I have tried disabling all the extensions and nothing worked.

Comment: after disabling all the extensions did you complete with cache clearing if not please do it. if you get this even after then delete all log and cache file from var folder

Comment: Please check your error log.

Comment: yes..i do cleared the cache and deleted the log and cache files from var folder...but no results.
The error log doesn't show any related errors.

Comment: check your server error logs.A blank page means some error at PHP level.Which will be logged at server logs.